# c# cannot insert data into database

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, c++11

I tired to my code, i have no idea whats wrong with my code
please help me to fix this
This code should insert the data into database, here im using ms access

this is my file staff.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace TestStaff
{
    public partial class Staff : Form
    {
        private OleDbConnection Kei = new OleDbConnection();
        public Staff()
        {
            Kei.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D://amel ioop//SalonDatabase.accdb;
            Persist Security info=False;";
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        private void Staff_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            new StaffClass().fefefe (Name.Text, DateofBirth.Text, Gender.Text, ICNumber.Text, Email.Text, Mobile.Text, Position.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

this the other file staffclass.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestStaff
{

    class StaffClass
    {
        private OleDbConnection connection;
        private OleDbCommand _command;
        private OleDbDataReader _reader;
        private string _NAME, _DOB, _EM, _IC, _GE, _MO, _PO;


        public OleDbConnection Connection
        {
            get
            {
                return connection;
            }
        }
        public OleDbCommand Command
        {
            get
            {
                return _command;
            }
            set
            {
                _command = value;
            }
        }
        public OleDbDataReader Reader
        {
            get
            {
                return _reader;
            }
            set
            {
                _reader = value;
            }
        }
        public string NAME
        {
            get
            {
                return _NAME;
            }
            set
            {
                _NAME = value;
            }
        }
        public string IC
        {
            get
            {
                return _IC;
            }
            set
            {
                _IC = value;
            }
        }
        public string MO
        {
            get
            {
                return _MO;
            }
            set
            {
                _MO = value;
            }
        }
        public string GE
        {
            get
            {
                return _GE;
            }
            set
            {
                _GE = value;
            }
        }

        public string EM
        {
            get
            {
                return _EM;
            }
            set
            {
                _EM = value;
            }
        }

        public string PO
        {
            get
            {
                return _PO;
            }
            set
            {
                _PO = value;
            }
        }

        public string DOB
        {
            get
            {
                return _DOB;
            }
            set
            {
                _DOB = value;
            }
        }


         public StaffClass()
        {
            connection = new OleDbConnection();
            connection.ConnectionString = connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=‪D://amel ioop//SalonDatabase.accdb;
            Persist Security Info=False;";
            connection.Open();
        }

         public bool fefefe(string _NAME, string _DOB, string _IC, string _MO, string _GE, string _EM, string _PO)
         {
             try
             {
                 OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                 command.Connection = connection;
                 command.CommandText = "insert into Staff (Name, DateofBirth, ICNumber, MobileNumber, Gender, EmailAddress, Position) values (@_NAME, @_DOB, @_IC, @_MO, @_GE, @EM, @_PO)";
                 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_NAME", NAME);
                 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_DOB", DOB);
                 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_IC", IC);
                 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_MO", MO);
                 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_GE", GE);
                 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_EM", EM);
                 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_PO", PO);
                 command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 MessageBox.Show("Data Saved");
                 connection.Close();
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
             }
             return true;
         }



    }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: have you used the debugger to step through the code line by line .. are you having any connection string / connection issues...? also wrap that code around a `using(){}` so that it will take advantage of the auto disposing when and where do you open the connection??

Comment: Does it work once, and then not a second time? Why are you closing the connection inside the insert, if you create and open it in the constructor?

Comment: @anthonywibow please do a MSDN search on C# property's and how to use them as well as assign them .. also it appears that you never debugged your own code otherwise you would have notice the many things that you are doing wrong here

Answer (score 2):

First thing I notice is that you are not assigning your property values. 
You are passing in _NAME to fefefefe but I don't see where you are assigning the Property NAME to the value _NAME.

A quick fix would be to use the parameters of the function instead of the property values. (ex)

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_NAME", _NAME);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_DOB", _DOB);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_IC", _IC);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_MO", _MO);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_GE", _GE);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_EM", _EM);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_PO", _PO);
```

Also, are you getting any type of exceptions?

Comment: Based on the info available I would say you are correct.  Assuming one of the values in that insert is a primary key, or any of the columns are marked not null, an exception would be thrown with something along the lines of "Cannot insert the value NULL into column"